# How to do pairing with BLE device after GATT connection

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, gatt

How to do pairing with BLE device after GATT connection because I have to do it manually , then I am able to get response from BLE device .

```
bluetoothComponent.gatt = tempdevice.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, 
                                                 bluetoothComponent.callbacknew);
```

Please help ,me out how to do pairing with BLE device after getting connected with BLE device .

Answer (score 0):

It can be done at your request with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createBond()
Also the peripheral may initiate the pairing.